# ViewData[var] being populated by the same SelectList, not a different one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a list of Band Titles, and I wish to attach a SelectList with each one of them, depending on the BandID.

So first I am getting the list:-

```
List<BandQuestionTitles> bandQuestTitles = viewModel.PopulateBandQuestionTitles();
```

and then I have a loop on the BandQuestionTitles to populate a ViewData[var] from a SelectList:-

```
foreach (var bandQuestTitleItem in bandQuestTitles)
    {
        //populate the dropdownlist
        string strViewDataString = bandQuestTitleItem.BandQuestTitlesText + "Data";
        ViewData[strViewDataString] = new SelectList(viewModel.bandQuestionList.Where(p => p.BandQuestTitleID == bandQuestTitleItem.BandQuestTitlesID), "BandQuestID", "BandQuestText");
    }
```

However for some reason, although I am getting correctly the 7 ViewData[""], I am always getting the same SelectList

When I hard code it, it works fine :-

```
ViewData["PersonalData"] = new SelectList(viewModel.bandQuestionList.Where(p => p.BandQuestTitleID == 1), "BandQuestID", "BandQuestText");
ViewData["BusinessData"] = new SelectList(viewModel.bandQuestionList.Where(p => p.BandQuestTitleID == 2), "BandQuestID", "BandQuestText");
```

What am I doing wrong in the loop?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: How are you rendering the SelectList on the View? e.g. @Html.DropDownList("PersonalData", "--Select--") ?

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("D_Personal", ViewData["PersonalData"] as SelectList, new { @class = "BigDropdowns" })

Comment: Hate to ask this but are you sure that BandQuestTitlesID is not the same for all of the bandQuestTitleItem instances in bandQuestTitles?

Comment: valid question!  I already checked and yes it is different for each one of them, ranging from 1 to 7 correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a problem with your LINQ not being executed when you think it is.

Try this:

```
new SelectList(viewModel.bandQuestionList.Where(p => p.BandQuestTitleID == bandQuestTitleItem.BandQuestTitlesID)**.ToList()**, "BandQuestID", "BandQuestText");
```

Relevant article from MS:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633.aspx

> In a query that returns a sequence of values, the query variable itself never holds the query results and only stores the query commands. Execution of the query is deferred until the query variable is iterated over in a foreach or For Each loop. This is known as deferred execution; that is, query execution occurs some time after the query is constructed.

In other words, when the queries are executed bandQuestTitleItem.BandQuestTitlesID will be assigned to the last(7th) ID in your collection for all of the queries.

Adding the .ToList() will cause the queries to execute immediately.

Comment: Excellent response! Thanks Ryan